# Jest test Redux Saga Cannot read property 'then' of undefined on dispatch

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, redux-saga

I've seen a couple of similar entries in stack overflow, but it doesn't quite relate to this issue I'm facing. We're using Jest for testing, and redux-saga for storage.

Recently we have tried to move away from Jasmine and move towards Jest. This test used to work for Jasmine but failing for Jest.

Here is the offending test,

```
  describe('componentWillReceiveProps method', () => {
    it('should call dispatch if entityType is changed', (done) => {
      const {wrapper, props} = setup();
      wrapperInstance = wrapper.instance();
      wrapperInstance.isPagePoppedFromHistory = false;

      setTimeout(() => {
        expect(props.dispatch).toHaveBeenCalled();
        done();
      }, 300);
      wrapperInstance.UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps(Object.assign({}, props, {
        entityType: {key: ENTITY_TYPE_HCO}
      }));
    });
  });
```

the error received is

```
Error: Uncaught [TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined]
        at reportException (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/helpers/runtime-script-errors.js:62:24)
        at Timeout.callback [as _onTimeout] (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/browser/Window.js:645:7)
        at ontimeout (timers.js:498:11)
        at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:323:5)
        at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:290:5) TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
        at UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps.setTimeout (/index.js:294:11)
        at Timeout.callback [as _onTimeout] (/Window.js:643:19)
        at ontimeout (timers.js:498:11)
        at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:323:5)
        at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:290:5)
```

the component offending code lines are these

```
componentWillReceiveProps(){
 ...
 setTimeout(() => {
          dispatch(fetchTableResults(resultsLimit, filterParams, qString, currentOrderOption,
            undefined, undefined, resultBounds))
            .then(() => {
              dispatch(changePageNumber(nextPage));
            });
        });

 ...
}
```

Any idea as to why we're seeing this? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: check what u have mock for `fetchTableResults` this should return thenable object(Promise)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up mocking dispatch method as xdeepakv suggested.